# Can't get Logback Eclipse plugin to display output

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, logback

I followed these instructions here:
http://logback.qos.ch/consolePlugin.html

I have the correct and found logback.xml, it is set up correctly, and the port is listening. Nothing shows up with

```
logger.error("Test");
```

It logs to sysout fine when I remove logback.xml, which shows to me that the logback is working fine. I installed the plugin on linux by moving it to /usr/lib/eclipse/plugins  ...The window shows up, but no logging events are showing up. I also added a catch all ACCEPT filter like on that link.

Perhaps this is a linux permission issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At present time (Marc 2010), the console plugin requires logback version 0.9.9 it will not work with other versions of logback. We intend to fix this problem after logback version 0.9.19 is released.